# How to get the next auto-increment id in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-increment, information-schema

How to get the next id in mysql to insert it in the table ?

```
INSERT INTO payments (date, item, method, payment_code)
VALUES (NOW(), '1 Month', 'paypal', CONCAT("chaminda", id))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach for this.

```
Step 1: Insert without payment_code.

Step 2: Get mysql_insert_id from STEP 1.

Step 3: Update payment_code with where condition as mysql_insert_id.
```

**Code Snippet in Php:**
 The commands might have to be corrected.

```
1.    mysql_query("INSERT INTO payments (date, item, method, payment_code)
    VALUES (NOW(), '1 Month', 'paypal')");

2.     printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());

3.     mysql_query(“UPDATE payments set payment_code=CONCAT("chaminda",mysql_insert_id()) where id=mysql_insert_id());
```

Comment: I need SQL query without any php code.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
INSERT INTO payments (date, item, method, payment_code)
VALUES (NOW(), '1 Month', 'paypal', NULL);

UPDATE payments
set payment_code=CONCAT("chaminda",LAST_INSERT_ID())
where id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: I think `last_insert_id()` returns whichever ID was issued last, not necessary from the given table.  And it has other problems, too, read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id.  Also, always explain why and how your solution works.